# Unmarshal same json object with different key to go slice struct

Tags: json, go

I can't figure out how I can serialize the same JSON object with a different key to Go slice struct without re-writing entire parser. 
For example, JSON that I can receive back, it might contain N number object with a different key (localhost1/localhost2/localhost3, etc). In this example, I have a key localhost1/localhost2/localhost3, and each has only one field ok.

```
{
"stats": {
        "localhost1": {
            "ok": 1
        },
        "localhost2": {
            "ok": 1
        },
        "localhost3": {
            "ok": 1
        }
     }
}
```

I can Unmarsh entire JSON by using the following Structs mappings.

```
type HostStatus struct {
        Ok int `json:"ok"`
}

type Test struct {
    Stats struct {
        Localhost1 HostStatus `json:"localhost1"`
        Localhost2 HostStatus `json:"localhost2"`
        Localhost3 HostStatus `json:"localhost3"`
    }  `json:"stats"`
}
```

Entire Example.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)
type HostStatus struct {
        Ok int `json:"ok"`
}

type Test struct {
    Stats struct {
        Localhost1 HostStatus `json:"localhost1"`
        Localhost2 HostStatus `json:"localhost2"`
        Localhost3 HostStatus `json:"localhost3"`
    }  `json:"stats"`
}


func main() {
    var resp = []byte(`{
        "stats": {
            "localhost1": {
            "ok": 1
        },
        "localhost2": {
            "ok": 1
        },
        "localhost3": {
            "ok": 1
        }
        }
    }`)

    var r Test
    er := json.Unmarshal(resp, &r)
    if er != nil {
        panic(er)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

The main issue in this solution that it requires hardcode inside a Stats struct each HostStatus that maps 1:1 to JSON output via json:xxx tag. 
But I want to find a way to map all this object to a HostStatus slice/array
since I don't know how many HostStatus objects I might receive back and what is the key for each.

For example something like

```
type Test struct {
    Stats struct {
        LocalHostList []HostStatus `json:"localhost[0-9]"`
    }  `json:"stats"`
}
```

and use something like localhost[0-9] -- i.e regex semantics that will give a hit to JSON package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Unmarshal Dynamic Viper or JSON keys as part of struct field in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749869/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
type Test struct {
    Stats map[string]HostStatus `json:"stats"`
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  ! That was exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know unmarshal() smart enough to map key to object.  Very nice solution

Comment: What if I need to preserve the order?

Comment: If you need to preserve the order of key-value pairs in a JSON object, you can use a `json.Decoder` and parse it yourself, or use one of the available JSON libraries. I wrote one recently that resembles XML's DOM model: https://github.com/bserdar/jsonom